# Проблема с срабатыванием события c# wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, делегаты

Есть 2 ViewModel это LoginViewModel и AuthViewModel
В AuthViewModel идет инициализация и вызов делегата при срабатывании команды

```
public event EventHandler LoginCompleted;
    public ICommand AuthCommand => new Commands.RelayCommand(o => AuthMethod(o));

    public void AuthMethod(object parametr)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Авторизация успешна");
        LoginCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

И я сделал унаследование LoginViewModel от AuthViewModel чтоб в App.xaml.cs
был виден делегат.
App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        LoginWindow LoginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        LoginWindow.DataContext = new ViewModels.LoginViewModel();
        LoginWindow.Show();
        ((ViewModels.LoginViewModel)LoginWindow.DataContext).LoginCompleted += (s, ev) =>
        {
            Window MainWindow = new MainWindow();
            LoginWindow.Hide();
            LoginWindow.Close();
            MainWindow.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
            MainWindow.Show();
        };
    }
```

При клике на кнопку срабатываем команда и вызывается MessageBox но почему то окно LoginWindow не закрывается.

Есть способ AuthViewModel удалить и все сделать в LoginViewModel и так даже все работает. Но мне почему то кажется что не очень красиво в VM окна авторизации/регистрации делать VM страницы авторизации. Ведь у меня еще страница будет Register.xaml и для нее будет свой VM. Получается для Register.xaml есть свой VM а для Login.xaml не будет.

Comment: Поставьте в этой строчке `LoginCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` точку останова и поглядите, сколько у события подписчиков. Есть мнение, что вы либо подписываетесь поздно, либо подписываетесь не на тот объект.

Comment: Не особо понял где нужно конкретно смотреть но в Target написано LoginWindow